# No \author given for titling package with amsart

Tags: author, titling

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{titling}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The code above gives the error message below:

> You have used the \maketitle command, but have not specified any
> \author. To fix this, include an author in your preamble using the
> \author{…} command.

How can I fix it? To be specific I do **not** need an author to be shown, I would just like to clear the error message.

Comment: I'd say that `titling` isn't compatible with `amsart`. Can you please be more specific about what you want to get?

Comment: I think `titling` is aimed at the standard classes i.e. `article`, `report` and `book` and it isn't really intended for use with arbitrary classes.